# I saved my file in xcode & entire font colour of that file became black

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I think my file has been corrupted, I click on save file and now it isnt showing colourful font as xCode show bt other files r colorful.

Comment: Which file are you talking about ?

Comment: I'v solved it. .m file was created once again, so that .m file wasn't having .h, so it was showing without extension, since xCode didn't knowing about the extension, which type of that file was, so xcode was failed to color the font & format accordingly. Thats why it was appeared to me as black & white file.

Comment: Gr8 ... Anything else let me knw ....

Comment: thnx for ur concern Gill

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry, Clean ur app or Build it , it should be alright. Or restart your xcode and everything will be fine :) ... Or check your .m and .h files ..